# Problem by using interpolated ik motion planner

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, recently i have tried to port the ros tabletop object_manipulation to our own robot. And i occur the problem that the interpolated ik motion planner can only accept 'r' and 'l' as argument. The generated arm navigation launch file has another arm name such like 'kuka'. Is that a way to go around this problem or do i have to manually modify the source code in the interpolated ik motion planner to enable of using other arms.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39759/problem-by-using-interpolated-ik-motion-planner/) by [dong](https://answers.ros.org/users/818/dong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this issue for me by commenting out two lines in *interpolated_ik_motion_planner/scripts/interpolated_ik_motion_planner.py* as below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    which_arm = None
#    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
#        which_arm = sys.argv[1]
    interpolated_ik_service = InterpolatedIKService(which_arm)
    rospy.loginfo("Ready to serve interpolated IK motion plan requests.")

    rospy.spin()
```

Here is my launch file, which makes the planner connect to the services it needs (e.g. IK):

```
<launch>
  <group ns="your_robot_name">
    <node name="interpolated_ik_node" pkg="interpolated_ik_motion_planner" type="interpolated_ik_motion_planner.py" args="" respawn="false">
      <param name="robot_prefix" type="string" value="your_robot_name"/>
      <param name="num_steps" type="int" value="0"/>
      <param name="pos_spacing" type="double" value="0.02"/>
      <param name="rot_spacing" type="double" value="0.0349065850399"/>
      <param name="collision_check_resolution" type="int" value="0"/>
      <param name="consistent_angle" type="double" value="0.017"/>
      <param name="collision_aware" type="int" value="1"/>
      <param name="start_from_end" type="int" value="0"/>
    </node>
  </group>
</launch>
```

Hope this works for you as well!

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2012-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-08**:
Doesn't this disable handling of the arm parameter completely?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-11-09**:
Correct, but if you have only one arm, that doesn't matter. If you still want to use multiple arms on the same robot, you will need to tweak the logic in that argv parsing or you use topic remappings for each node. I guess, this usage of argv is, because this tool was initial used via rosrun.